# MONO: porting .net to Linux.

Tags: mono

We have an existing legacy .NET application written in C# and some C++ code which is still being developed on windows. The question of switching to Linux as the development environment is being discussed and we heard about Mono project. Here are some questions we have which we hope we can get some answers.

1- By installing Mono on Linux, can we make Linux the build platform for the existing code?

2- If the answer to the above is yes, do the customers need to have Mono installed on their Linux boxes?

3- If we can not switch the build platform to Linux, but build the product using Mono on Windows, Do the customers need to have Mono installed on their Linux boxes? or Will bundling the Mono runtime libraries with the product work?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

with serious efforts you can create anything with linux. It's opensource.

You can use linux not only for building, but for development too.

To bundle runtime into executable you can use at least 2 non-linux ways - mkbundle or compiling code into native code (with msil to llvm compiler).

linux way is to add dependency on mono into package for your product.

Comment: does building the executable using mono on windows(.net) impact the performance?  Also could you explain what you mean by " linux way is to add dependency on mono package"?